# What is the equivalent of getValue() in Firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

there is function called in Firebase Realtime database"getValue()", What is it's equivalent in firestore database? below is the code I have which is based on Firebase Realtime Database, I have managed to change all other things only this thing is left

```
SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage> parser = new SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage>() {
            @Override
            public FriendlyMessage parseSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
                if (friendlyMessage != null) {
                    friendlyMessage.setId(dataSnapshot.getId());
                }
                return friendlyMessage;
            }
};
```

Comment: In which context? What are trying to achieve?

Comment: I suppose, you are looking for `toObject`.

Comment: @AlexMamo I am following this tutorial for chat which is Realtime database, and I am converting it into Firestore database, and this problem is the step 8 of the tutorial

Comment: If you consider to use Firestore, here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: @Ranjan I think that is indeed what OP is looking for. Can you write it up into an answer, showing how to use `toObject` to map the data from a document to a custom Java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think OP is looking for a way to convert `DocumentSnapshot` into a Java object. The equivalent method in `firestore` is `toObject`. Here is an example from the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects) -

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ");
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        City city = documentSnapshot.toObject(City.class);
    }
});
```

In your case, it will be -

```
FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.toObject(FriendlyMessage.class);
```